# How to write a query in @query annotation having DTO class constructor in it?

Tags: spring-boot

This is my repository and ChecklistCitem is my DTO class:

```
@Query(value="SELECT new com.inspectionApp.CheckList.DTO.ChecklistCitem(p.identifier,p.title,p.descrp,p.checklistIdentifier,p.checklistItemType,c.identifier,c.title,c.descrp,c.checklistType,c.isActive)"
        + "FROM ChecklistItemPool p INNER JOIN Checklist c ON p.checklistIdentifier=c.identifier",nativeQuery=true)
List<ChecklistCitem> fetchAll();

}
```

And I am getting this error:

```
 """com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.'."""
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a constructor inside the native query? 
If it is for returning the results of query inside the object then there are some better options available.

Comment: You can only use that in a JPQL **not** in a plain SQL query.